# Toggle named range window with a button?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-named-ranges

I would like to know if it would be possible to toggle the different features in sheets with a script.

What I am trying to do is to basically create a button that will show the Named Ranges side panel without having to go `Data > Named Ranges`.

How can I script this?

Comment: I don't think that this will be possible due to [HTML Service Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)

Answer (score 2):

Per @Rubén's comment, it doesn't appear possible to call up interface items in the way you describe.

However, you can make use of the native [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

To get to Named Ranges on a PC:

1. In Google Chrome: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>. Other browsers: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>n</kbd>.

On a Mac:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>n</kbd>.